# Bind a multiple properties of a button in WPF to a class

Tags: wpf

I'm not sure if this is possible but I'm looking for a way to bind a button to a generic class that contain all the properties i will need to use.  Every button needs a relay command so that would be included but all of our buttons will need to bind visibility and being enabled.  Instead of having this group of properties and relay command for every button we will use within the given windows view model I was wondering if there was a way to have the button bind to a class then in our view model we reference a new instance of that class for each button needed and then be just be able to set the properties on that class to the values we need.  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a bunch of different ways to do something like this. I don't know if I'd choose to have a class instance for each button. But here's a rough/quick/dodgy example of a solution.

The main model for the form is providing the button models by way of a list. The individual button models then handle the button bindings.

EDIT: Extended the code a bit. Now includes command bindings. Also shows use of `ItemsControl` as suggested by @Xavier. Hope it helps.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400">
    <StackPanel>

        <!-- Known buttons -->
        <StackPanel Margin="20">
            <Button DataContext="{Binding ButtonModels[0], Mode=OneTime}" Content="{Binding LabelText}" Background="{Binding Colour}" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}" />
            <Button DataContext="{Binding ButtonModels[1], Mode=OneTime}" Content="{Binding LabelText}" Background="{Binding Colour}" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}" />
            <Button DataContext="{Binding ButtonModels[2], Mode=OneTime}" Content="{Binding LabelText}" Background="{Binding Colour}" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- Dynamic buttons -->
        <StackPanel Margin="20">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonModels}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="{Binding LabelText}" Background="{Binding Colour}" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new Model();
        }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        private Random rnd = new Random();
        public List<ButtonModel> ButtonModels { get; private set; }

        public Model()
        {
            this.ButtonModels = new List<ButtonModel>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                this.ButtonModels.Add(new ButtonModel
                {
                    LabelText = "Button " + (i + 1),
                    Command = new RelayCommand((index) => { this.ChangeColour((int)index); }),
                    CommandParameter = i
                });
            }
        }

        private void ChangeColour(int index)
        {
            this.ButtonModels[index].Colour = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)rnd.Next(50, 256), (byte)rnd.Next(50, 256), (byte)rnd.Next(50, 256)));
        }
    }

    public class ButtonModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private string _LabelText;
        public string LabelText { get => _LabelText; set => this.SetProperty(ref _LabelText, value); }

        private Brush _Colour = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(205, 205, 205));
        public Brush Colour { get => _Colour; set => this.SetProperty(ref _Colour, value); }

        private RelayCommand _Command;
        public RelayCommand Command { get => _Command; set => this.SetProperty(ref _Command, value); }

        private int _CommandParameter;
        public int CommandParameter { get => _CommandParameter; set => this.SetProperty(ref _CommandParameter, value); }
    }

    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (field == null && value == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (field == null || !field.Equals(value))
            {
                field = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent(propertyName);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Predicate<object> canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> action, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = action;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good start, but rather than list each individual button in the xaml like that, just use an `ItemsControl` that is bound to the list. Give it a data template for a single button, and it will apply it to all of them.

Comment: Well, yes. I did say it was "rough/quick/dodgy". Not sure if OP's scenario involved known buttons or dynamic buttons. Probably the later.

Comment: Thanks this really helped me out.  This would be used for both dynamic as well as already known buttons.  Can you please explain this "I  don't know if I'd choose to have a class instance for each button" and what you would do instead.

Comment: Also can you please help me out as to how you would bind the command to this.  Thanks

Comment: @NormTheThird, I was thinking that an object for each button was a bit of overkill. But I'm reconsidering. It depends on the complexity I guess. Anyhoo, I've updated the code to show an example command binding.